# ubuntu 20.04 apache2 server failed

Tags: server, apache2, 20.04

Just upgraded to ubuntu 20.04 from 19.10. and after the restart I noticed my apache server is failed.
I ran `systemctl restart apache2` that showed

```
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

then i ran `systemctl status apache2.service` that gave this

```
 ● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor prese>
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2020-05-08 02:14:14 +06; 22s >
       Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/
    Process: 3271 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FA>

May 08 02:14:14 mahmud systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
May 08 02:14:14 mahmud apachectl[3281]: apache2: Syntax error on line 146 of /e>
May 08 02:14:14 mahmud apachectl[3271]: Action 'start' failed.
May 08 02:14:14 mahmud apachectl[3271]: The Apache error log may have more info>
May 08 02:14:14 mahmud systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, cod>
May 08 02:14:14 mahmud systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-co>
May 08 02:14:14 mahmud systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

Here's the `apachectl configtest`

```
apache2: Syntax error on line 146 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 3 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php7.3.load: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7.3.so into server: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7.3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

what should I do?

Comment: Fix the weeoe on line 146 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf ... what ever it is.

Comment: It was conflict between 2 php version. Disabling previous version did the trick

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem when i upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04. During the upgrade process, my php package 7.2 was removed. However, the upgrade process did not remove php7.2 configurations. Thus, I had to disable the php7.2 mod and install the latest version of php, which is 7.4.

In your case, you will have to disable php7.3 and install php7.4.

I used the following commands:

```
sudo a2dismod php7.3
sudo a2enmod php7.4
```

To undo use the following command:

```
sudo a2dismod php7.4
sudo a2enmod php7.3
```

To list apache2 mods use the following:

```
sudo a2query -m
```

After you make any changes, you will need to restart apache2.

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Just using a2dismod php7.3 was enough still I used a2enmod php7.4 and its working perfectly. Thanks

Comment: In my case was [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68427284/4970442) regarding libpcre2-8.so.0 symlink pointing to the incorrect file..